# Can a unique solution exist for this boundary value problem?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, boundary-value-problem, laplacian

I have the following boundary value problem:

$$\nabla^2 T(x,y,z)=0$$

defined over $x\in[0,L], y\in[0,l], z\in[0,w]$ and subjected to

$$\frac{\partial T(0,y,z)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial T(L,y,z)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial T(x,0,z)}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial T(x,l,z)}{\partial y}=0$$

and

$$\frac{\partial T(x,y,0)}{\partial z}=A (T(x,y,0)-t_1)$$
$$\frac{\partial T(x,y,w)}{\partial z}=B (t_2-T(x,y,w))$$

$A,B$ are constants $>0$ and $t_1,t_2$ are functions of $T$.

**Will the above system have a unique solution ?**

---

Form of $t_1$ and $t_2$

$$t_1=e^{-b_c y/l}\left[t_{ci} + \frac{b_c}{l}\int_0^y e^{b_c s/l}T(x,s,0)ds\right]$$

$$t_2=e^{-b_h x/L}\left[t_{hi} + \frac{b_h}{L}\int_0^x e^{b_h s/L}T(x,s,w)ds\right]$$

$t_{hi}, t_{ci}, b_c, b_h$ are all constants greater than zero.

Comment: It looks like the wave equation of a rectangle , which has multiple harmonics. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WaveEquationRectangle.html

Comment: @arthur This is the Laplacian:$$\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial z^2}=0$$. And yes the solution if it exists will be a summation of multiple harmonics. But does a solution exist for this set of boundary conditions ? Thanks for the reference.

Comment: Provided $t_1$ and $t_2$ are well behaved (I believe $L^2$ will suffice), you can explicitly solve this PDE through separation of variables. You get an additional compatibility condition on the boundary conditions when doing this. This at least partially addresses the existence portion.

Comment: @Kajelad I have added the structure of $t_1,t_2$. They are actually functions of $T$. If I may ask, can you elaborate a little on what you mean by additional compatibility conditions ?

Comment: When solving the separated system, you end up with a of linear system for each Fourier sine component the $xy$-plane. These must be solvable to proceed.